# wordpress bloginfo('template_directory'); parsing as a string using twig

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, url, twig

I'm trying to use a wordpress function which leads your path to the root of your theme in wordpress by doing:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/art.svg" alt="">
```

The issue is that if I inspect this I realise that the php code is parsed as a string instead of inserting a path to root of the theme. What am I doing wrong?

FYI: I'm using twig.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used Twig within Symfony, but never within WordPress.  From my experience, in order to access functions such as `bloginfo` you will need to extend Twig to allow it.

This will require quite a bit of deep integration, and probably out of the scope of what you're asking for here.

More information: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#functions

That said, it appears someone has done the hard work for you.  Timber is a WordPress to Twig implementation: http://upstatement.com/timber/

**Edit:** More [here](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/WP-Integration#functions), basically the syntax is `{{function('FUNCTION NAME', 'ARGUMENT ONE', 'ARGUMENT TWO')}}`, so in this case: `<img src="{{function('bloginfo','template_directory')}}/images/art.svg" alt="">`

Comment: I'm trying to find my way, it seems you need to create your own url's? Do you know how this works?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki#if-statement) has an example which uses `bloginfo`.  Maybe give that a go?  Failing that you'll need to put the `bloginfo` call into a variable in your theme PHP files and then print it like any other variable.

Comment: More [here](https://github.com/jarednova/timber/wiki/WP-Integration#functions), basically the syntax is `{{function('FUNCTION NAME', 'ARGUMENT ONE', 'ARGUMENT TWO')}}`, so in this case: `<img src="{{function('bloginfo','template_directory'}}/images/art.svg" alt="">`

Comment: In Timber the site object holds all your answers. For example...

    <?php
    $context = Timber::get_context();
    Timber::render('single.twig', $context);

Then in your twig template...

    <img src="{{site.theme.link}}/images/art.svg" /> 

... for the *current theme* directory (the equivalent of stylesheet_directory). Or:

    <img src="{{site.theme.parent.link}}"/images/art.svg" />

... for the current *parent theme* directory (the equivalent of template_directory).

Answer (score 4):

In Timber the site object holds all your answers. For example...

```
<?php
$context = Timber::get_context();
Timber::render('single.twig', $context);
```

Then in your twig template...

```
<img src="{{site.theme.link}}/images/art.svg" />
```

... for the *current theme* directory (the equivalent of stylesheet_directory). Or:

```
<img src="{{site.theme.parent.link}}"/images/art.svg" />
```

... for the current *parent theme* directory (the equivalent of template_directory).

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/art.svg" alt="">
```

You forgot to echo out the information.

Comment: Even with the echo the url prints the whole php function as a string